# How do you make your PHP server read your socket you just created?

Tags: php, sockets

I am making a PHP socket server but am unable to make my server read the socket.

```
    $this->log("Creating socket (please wait)...");

    $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if(socket_bind($this->socket, "127.0.0.1", 8080) === false){
        $this->log("Failed to bind socket to port (8080)");
        exit();
    }
    socket_listen($this->socket, 5);

    if(!is_resource($this->socket)){
        $this->log("Socket isn't a resource. Something went wrong, exiting.");
        exit();
    }

    $this->log("Socket created, creating socket reader...");
    $this->socketReader = new SocketReader($this);

    $this->log("server started");

    //socket should be non-blocking
    socket_set_nonblock($this->getSocket());

    //called every 10000 microseconds to read socket (error line here)
    public function process(){
        $buffer = socket_read($this->getSocket(), 128);
        var_dump($buffer);,
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
`Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [57]: Socket is not connected` when calling proccess().
```

Why is this? The socket is created successfully but it errors when I try to read potential incoming data.

Comment: You have to call `socket_accept()` to return a new socket connected to an incoming connection.

Comment: @Barmar If I call that, server freezes. And if I call that set_non_block, it will return false. I don't want the server to wait for connections, just detect them passively on ticks.

Comment: Make it non-blocking, and call `socket_accept` periodically. If it returns false, there's no connection to process. When it returns a resource, you can read from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `socket_accept()` to get a new socket for the incoming connection, and then read from that.

```
//called every 10000 microseconds to read socket
public function process(){
    $connection = socket_accept($this->getSocket());
    if ($connection) {
        socket_set_nonblock($connection);
        $buffer = socket_read($connection, 128);
        var_dump($buffer);
        socket_close($connection);
    }
}
```